# Are the current post notices friendly enough for new contributors?

Tags: discussion, new-users, post-notices, new-contributor-indicator

From [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/177201/11458) on English Language Learners:

[image]

I have a feeling that even post notices must include salutations like "Welcome!", "Hello!", "Thanks!". I also think for each site the notices must be customized. For example, in language-related site, this notice should have "You can further explain it by giving the definition in the dictionaries".

Is that necessary or is this enough?

Comment: These post notices are site-specific, so should be discussed on the site-specific meta. We discourage fluff like _Welcome_ and _Thanks_ in comments, questions and answers, so imo notices shouldn't have them as well

Comment: The welcome bandwagon only applies to the users, not to the site itself. :P

Comment: @Erik there are site-specific post notices but there are some (including the one above) that are global

Comment: @Cai That's new for me, thanks for the info! Never seen that one on any of the sites I frequent.

Comment: @Erik I think most sites simply don't use them, but they do exist

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth so is it my misunderstanding that the new policy encourage welcomes and thanks to new users? At least that's my impression that many sites have applied this before the policy.

Comment: @Ooker Yes, I think nothing has changed on that front. Under [/help/behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), we still have _Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings._ There has been discussion about being less aggressive in removing fluff, but nothing definitive. Also see [Welcoming Formalities vs Noise-free Conciseness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372224/7296893) on MSO. Basically, while we've done a whole lot of talking and writing on the welcoming thing, not much has changed. We still shouldn't be rude, and we still should be concise and factual.

Comment: Oh, and also [Should we really allow thank you comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309715/369403) here on MSE. They're still not appreciated.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think that can be a good answer.

Comment: Frankly, I find excessive pandering in salutations like "Welcome!", "Hello!", "Thanks!" to be very condescending.  Think about those automated attendants when you phone a company that make you throw up a little in your mouth every time you have to listen to one. Like too much warm syrup slathered over waffles, it eventually gives you diabetes.

Comment: Also, not to put too fine a point on this, but how insulting is it when a website, company or any other entity sees us as so fragile that we must be coddled in this way?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've seen some sites (maybe [interpersonal.se]) welcome new users with a whole paragraph before getting to the critics. I myself don't like sugarcoating too, but that's how I see in such sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're in the process of auditing all of the stuff that the *system* says, which includes:

- Post notices
- Warnings when using blacklisted links / tags / words
- We started looking at error messages, but something bad happened
- Moderator message templates
- 'Default' profile content
- I'm missing 20+ additional bullets here, there's a *lot*.

In *some* cases, language needs to be changed so the voice is understood to at least be supportive, ideally somewhat encouraging, and more often than not, ending in *something the user can actually go do*. We finally developed a UX writing standard and a better unified framework for presenting stuff to users, so we have *some* hope of a major audit ending up in the tone and wording being more consistent and more effective across the board.

You have to be careful with salutations though, *even in the system generated copy*, because circumstances can happen where the accidental irony is even more hurtful than the random *sort of* insensitive stuff that led to it.

We also have a lot of places where communities come up with their own wording, and we want to respect that *as* we try to achieve good consistency in tone and messaging, and that kind of collaboration takes time.

So your instinct here is really good, a lot of this stuff is 5+ years old and was great when it was written, but didn't age well. However, we have to look at *all* of it if we're going to look at any of it, or we just make the inconsistencies even more glaring.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the outcome of the audit. Onwards and upwards!