# Does it make sense to offer a bounty "Thanking users who answered my question" as Current answers are outdated?

Tags: discussion, bounties, stack-exchange, meta, specific-question

The accepted answer (+162 / -1) to [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878/289691) was last edited on Dec, 2017. It's a community wiki and includes the following

> First of all, anyone posting here with the idea that they should be
> personally thanked for every answer they provide is going to be very
> disappointed.
>
> If you *really* want to thank someone for a good answer, then you'll
> perhaps take the time to go through one of *their* questions and
> provide a good answer for some question *they* have.
>
> Alternately, **just "pay it forward" and answer another user's
> question**. That's really what it's all about.

Rhetorical question: *Do the latest "changes" from Stack Exchange Inc. / the Stack Exchange community and the world in general make showing **gratitude** such a big thing that we should do things differently?*

Is it worthwhile to offer a *50 rep* bounty to ask for a current answer considering that the most prominent answer is a community wiki, it's the accepted answer and it has such a high score?

---

Besides the *reactions test* being held in Stack Overflow, other features introduced recently are:

- "Following",
- "New asking experience",
- expanded user cards are shown for all users regardless of reputation,
- new sharing option available in Stack Overflow to share posts on https://dev.to,
- the *Reversal* and *Tumbleweed* **badges** were retired, "Lifejacket" and "Lifeboat" take their place.

Related

- [What do the plans for incorporating "new ways to say thanks" look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339283/289691)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/289691)

Comment: Regarding those "changes": those are clearly marked as a *test*, not as a permanent change. There's a chance that they may not roll out the change. It's also not rolled out on the other sites. I don't think that answer needs to be updated unless the changes were rolled out permanently.

Answer (score 2):

#### Possibly, but it's probably better to ask a new question.

I'm ignoring most of your post and answering this:

> Is it worthwhile to offer a 50 rep bounty to ask for a current answer considering that the most prominent answer is a community wiki, it's the accepted answer and it has such a high score?

- It being a "community wiki" is irrelevant IMHO.
- The acceptance could be outdated, or rather - valid at the time acceptance, and not necessarily in the present.
- About the vote count... well, you know what they say - "Opinions are like ********, everybody has one". I've seen plenty of good answers with low scores and vice-versa.

If the question itself needs current answers for people encountering the problem these days, then I suggest doing one of two things:

1. Ask a new question elaborating on the change in circumstances since the time of the previous question being asked. Mention the older question in the new one to get a 'Related' link, and make a comment on the old one linking to the new one and mentioning circumstances have changed.
2. A bounty or other means of attracting attention to the existing question + possible editing explaining that answers both for time period X and time period Y are acceptable.

I'd go with option (1.)